# Delphi; working example StringToComponent, ComponenttoString

Tags: forms, delphi, components

I am trying to save some components that were placed on a form at design time (to a file or database, for example) once they configured correctly. Then I would remove them. At runtime, I want to place the components back on the form depending upon the situation. In my case, I am editing tables, so I want one form that will adapt to the table that user chooses to edit. I don't want one form for each table.

i use these examples per Delphi documentation

```
function TfmTableEdit.MComponentToString(Component: TComponent): string;
var
  BinStream:TMemoryStream;
  StrStream: TStringStream;
  s: string;
begin
  BinStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    StrStream := TStringStream.Create(s);
    try
      BinStream.WriteComponent(Component);
      BinStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      ObjectBinaryToText(BinStream, StrStream);
      StrStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      Result:= StrStream.DataString;
    finally
      StrStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    BinStream.Free
  end;
end;
function TfmTableEdit.MStringToComponent(Value: string): TComponent;
var
  StrStream:TStringStream;
  BinStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  StrStream := TStringStream.Create(Value);
  try
    BinStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      ObjectTextToBinary(StrStream, BinStream);
      BinStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      Result:= BinStream.ReadComponent(nil);
    finally
      BinStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    StrStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

So, I used it on a component called UniDBEdit5 for testing and got this value.

'object UniDBEdit5: TUniDBEdit'#$D#$A'  Left = 288'#$D#$A'  Top = 376'#$D#$A'  Width = 121'#$D#$A'  Height = 22'#$D#$A'  Hint = '''''#$D#$A'  TabOrder = 5'#$D#$A'end'

so, i deleted the component to see if I could get it back. I get an fatal error, "control can not be created with a nil Owner", but this usage is right from the documentation.

My goal is saving many controls in a database, and when user chooses a particular form, at runtime the appropriate controls will be loaded onto the form in a particular configuration. The form would not know in advance what controls would be added, but i should have that information in the string, so for example i could call RegisterClass(TUniDBEdit) in advance.

Does anyone have a proper use of these functions? I have looked...
Thanks!
Doug

Comment: Well, essentially you don't need to save the control declaration in a text form but as a binary stream (saving it in a BLOB field). I understood your question though, you're just asking how to save and load the controls into the text and from the text form.

Comment: Thank you all, but it seems that this function is good for a component that is already on the form, but I am trying to load a component that does not yet exist on the form and whose name I would not yet know. For example, I want to add to a form 5 TuniDBEdits and 4 TuniLabels at run time, based on the strings that I saved previously.

Comment: You are trying to work with third party components. They can have some specific requirements, that standard components do not have. If they want Owner, than you can create them beforehand, passing your form as Owner. And only after that call MStringToComponent. But you will need to add new parameter, in order to be able to pass your empty components to ReadComponent.

Comment: You say: *...but it seems that this function is good for a component that is already on the form...* That is not correct. The demo code starts with an existing component only because it is easier to construct the string representation (and get it right). Nothing prevents you (I tested it) from writing the string from scratch and use it to create actual components. The owner is not set however. You could try if `InsertComponent(YourComp);` right after you created the control, helps (it inserts the component in the forms `Components` list and assigns the form as the owner of your component.

Comment: Thank you @Tom could you please give me a working example of: having the string generated from the original component, to reconstruct that component?

Comment: Sorry @douglas , as I don't have the `TUniDBEdit` component, I can't verify what would work.

Comment: Thank you Tom. it could be any component, i just happen to be using TUniDBEdit.